# Why is the Regex for my product's code not working?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do Regex code for product's code in VSCode's HTML. My product's code has the following conditions:

1. Required enter 6 characters
2. First 2 characters must be letter and uppercase
3. Next 4 characters must be numbers.

I have tried this regular expression and it doesn't work:

```
^[A-Z]{2}+\[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: Please share more details, like sample data to be matched and a clarifiaction about what "doesn't work" means. Also, you haven't shared any PHP code that helps to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$
```

This corrects the escaping of your character class; that made it no longer a character class but a series of characters to match in the regex, ending with 4 `]`s. The `+` also is not needed as the `{2}` is stating only 2 uppercase alpha characters are allowed.

You can also swap the `[0-9]` with `\d` which is the metacharacter for an integer. With PHP regexs you also need delimiters so something like:

```
/^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$/
```

could be used in `preg_match`.